# lapply 2 functions in one command

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, names

I want to change some names in the data frame `df`

```
> names(df)[17:26]
[1] "X1."  "X2."  "X3."  "X4."  "X5."  "X6."  "X7."  "X8."  "X9."  "X10."
```

I want "X" -> "Reach" and remove dots.
I used lapply:

```
change <- function(d){
    gsub("X","reach",d) 
    gsub("\\.","",d)
}
a <- as.character(lapply(names(df)[17:26], change))
```

But "X" didn't change. Why?

```
> a 
[1] "X1"  "X2"  "X3"  "X4"  "X5"  "X6"  "X7"  "X8"  "X9"  "X10"
```

Comment: That because you didn't save the results of your first operation. You should do `d <-  gsub("X","reach",d)` and then `gsub("\\.","",d)`.

Comment: You could also nest the two `gsub`s into each other: `gsub("X","reach", gsub("\\.","",d))`.

Comment: beginneR suggestion is even better. This way you can ditch the `for` loop and make your solution fully vectorized, as in `a <- gsub("X","reach", gsub("\\.","",names(df)[17:26]))`

Comment: Hi, Take a bit of time and read the tag excerpt before tagging. [tag:dataframes] is for pandas, whereas you need [tag:data.frame] here. Be careful the next time. See this meta post. [Warn \[r\] users from adding \[dataframes\] tag instead of \[data.frame\] tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318933)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in a single `gsub` using back references (the parenthesised parts of the pattern expression).

```
x <- names(df)[17:26]
gsub( "X([0-9]+)." , "Reach\\1" , x )
# [1] "Reach1"  "Reach2"  "Reach3"  "Reach4"  "Reach5"  "Reach6"  "Reach7"  "Reach8"  "Reach9"  "Reach10"
```

We match the digits in your names vector using `[0-9]+` and by surrounding them in parentheses we make what is known as a back reference. We can refer to stuff matched inside the parentheses by its back reference. Since this is the first set of parentheses, it's back reference is `\\1`. If we had another set of braces we could refer to this as `\\2`. So we match the `X`, then some numbers and then the `.`. We replace it with `Reach` and the numbers that matched within parentheses by referring to the back reference using `\\1`.

I hope this explanation makes sense! It isn't the clearest.